# PHP producing different results in cli and browser

Tags: php, browser, command-line-interface

This section of PHP code is producing far different results via the browser and via command line php.

```
for($i=0;$i<=35;$i++)
{
    echo $grid_array[$i];
    if ($grid_array[$i] == 0){
        echo "<img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=$i') src='./white.png'></img>";
    }
    if ($grid_array[$i] == 1){
        echo "<img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=$i') src='./black.png'></img>";
    }
}
```

Via command line, everything works as expected. The output is a mixture of "white" and "black" images, with either 0 or 1 preceding the tag.

Via browser, something weird happens:

> `<img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=0') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=1') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=2') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=3') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=4') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=5') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=6') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=7') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=8') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=9') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=10') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=11') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=12') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=13') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=14') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=15') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=16') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=17') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=18') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=19') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=20') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=21') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=22') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=23') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=24') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=25') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=26') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=27') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=28') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=29') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=30') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=31') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=32') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=33') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=34') src='./white.png'></img><img onclick=(document.cookie='click_id=35') src='./white.png'></img></p></body>`

Every single value is set to the white picture. I cant figure out why this is happening. grid_array is an array of values equaling either 0 or 1. VIa the browser, php seems to be ignoring the echo command as well.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you initializing $grid_array in both cases?

Comment: If `$grid_array` is same, then the result should be same.

Comment: That code cannot possibly output what you posted. Well, it can, but only if `$grid_array` contains only empty values (null or undefined).

Comment: That's a lot of obtrusive javascript!

Comment: $grid_array is loaded from a file that is created via a process that this same PHP script executes. When I run it in a command line, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how you initialized `$grid_array` - if it's a blank/non-existent array, then ALL indexes of that array will compare equal to `0`.

As well, your HTML is invalid. `<img>` tags do not have closing `</img>`. img tags are NOT containers. they're singletons.